# O que fazer quando o usuário achou a solução, mas não posta uma resposta?

Tags: debate

Boa tarde,

Uma coisa que ocorre com certa frequência é um usuário achar a resposta de sua própria pergunta sozinho/através de comentários, mas não postar ou aceitar uma resposta oficial.

Geralmente ele posta um comentário do genero:

> Achei a solução, era XXX! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Isto atrapalha pessoas procurando perguntas para responder, já que essas perguntas ficam classificadas como sem resposta aceita.

Nestes casos, como proceder? Atualmente eu deixo um comentário pedindo que seja postada uma resposta oficial, mas geralmente esses pedidos não são atendidos.

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que isso já foi respondido antes, estou procurando... Basicamente é pedir para ele fazer, se não o fizer, ou entender quer ele desapareceu do site, colocar você mesmo e tema a solução em comentário, poste como Community Wiki. Se for sua própria solução, só poste a resposta. Se não tem como responder, considere se dá para fechar por algum motivo. Em alguns casos extremos seria bom sinalizar, mas quase sempre a moderação não poderá fazer nada a mais, por isso não abuse da sinalização.

Comment: @bigown depois desse comentário vai ser irônico se você não responder a pergunta XD

Comment: acho que é duplicata, @Genos é interessante sempre dar uma pesquisada no META também.

Comment: Alguém encontrou onde esta pergunta foi respondida anteriormente?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, por favor, o que seria "**perquisar no meta**"? onde fica?  Obrigado!

Comment: @RobervalSena山本 Todos sites da rede Stack Exchange tem um subdominio que começa com `meta.`, que é inclusive aonde estamos, no meta do pt.stackoverflow.com, o sistema de pesquisa é igual do site principal, no META nós falamos sobre, comportamento na comunidade, bugs, solicitamos suporte sobre o uso, pedimos ferramentas ou coisas semelhantes novas, tudo isto destinado ao site principal. Então muitas duvidas durante estes 3 anos de SO em portugues já foram discutidos, por isso citei que acredito ser um dup, vou procura-la ;) Até mais.

Comment: Geralmente, quando é um problema tão específico que só o AP entende o que perguntou e o que respondeu, eu marco para fechar como "problema não pode ser reproduzido"